# Why does forward price equal spot price at delivery?

Tags: futures, forward

*Disclaimer: I understand this is a basic question that gets
addressed in most 101 textbooks. Yet I have reviewed many of them
not finding a satisfactory answer. Please bear with my
ignorance.*

Suppose a forward contract enforces the parties to exchange an
asset with price $K$ at the delivery date $t=T$, and suppose the
spot price of that asset at $t=T$ is $L$ (so both $K$ and $L$ are *constant*). Then the possessor of
the forward contract at $t=T$ is forced to buy the asset at price
$K$, and the possessor can also sell the asset immediately to
obtain $L$. That means, the possessor at time $t=T$ can
immediately earn $L-K$. Therefore anyone who are to buy that
future contract at $t=T$ must obviously pay $L-K$. This means
that the forward contract at $t=T$ should be of price $L-K$.

**However, all textbooks and resources I've seen claim that the
forward contract at $t=T$ should be of price $L$ instead of
$L-K$.**

Why so? What is wrong in my argument?

---

Another attempt I made to understand this point is by reading
[1]. In section 2.3, it provides a more detailed argument:

> As the delivery period for a futures contract is approached,
> the futures price converges to the spot price of the underlying
> asset. When the delivery period is reached, the futures price
> equals—or is very close to—the spot price. To see why this is
> so, we first suppose that the futures price is above the spot
> price during the delivery period. Traders then have a clear
> arbitrage opportunity:
>
> 1. Sell (i.e., short) a futures contract
> 2. Buy the asset
> 3. Make delivery.

But when I carry the cash flow out, I can't make that balance.

First, selling a future contract yields a flow `(-1 * future) + (+1 * future-price-at-time-T)`. Second, buying the asset yields a
flow `(+1 * asset) + (-1 * spot-price-at-time-T)`. Third, making
delivery yields a flow `(-1 * asset) + K`. The net balance of
three flows is

```
+ 1 * future-price-at-time-T
- 1 * spot-price-at-time-T
- 1 * future
+ K
```

I can't tell why if `+ 1 * future-price-at-time-T - 1 * spot-price-at-time-T > 0` then there is an arbitrage opportunity.

---

Thanks for your patience and sharing.

#### Reference

- [1] Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives by John C. Hull

Comment: $L - K$ is a function of time. As the difference between $t$ and $T$ shrinks, $L-K$ shrinks

Comment: @amdopt I defined $L$ as the spot price at time $t=T$, and $K$ as the delivery price. Both are constant.

Comment: @Student, Yes, they are constant because time has run out on the contract when $t=T$. If you modeled out the relationship over a period of time, you would see that $L$ and $K$ converge to the same price at time $T$. So, if you made them constant at $T$, they are the same and $L-K=0$

Comment: @amdopt Interesting, so now we have three different claims. The textbooks claim that the final price of the future contract will be the spot price $L$. I claim that the price (at time $t=T$) will be $L-K$, which is usually nonzero. And you claim that $L-K=0$. I don't know how to resolve the differences.. Could you please elaborate why $L-K=0$, and what the price of the future contract should be at delivery time (i.e. $t=T$)?

Comment: My claim and the claim in the textbook are the same. The price of the futures contract when $t=T$ is, and should be the spot price.

Comment: @amdopt And my very question is why...

Comment: A forward contract that delivers $K (\neq L)$ must be priced at $L-K$ at $t=T$, as you yourself pointed out.  But this is no different to a forward contract that delivers $K=L$ and is priced at $L-K=0$ at $t=T$.  It's like saying you get 1000 barrels of oil and \$2000, and I want to see spot oil + \$2 (in $/bbl).

Comment: I now see my confusion. What I did for forward contract is correct, and as @hroptatyr pointed out, it must be priced at $L-K$ at delievery time. The thing whose price converges to the spot price is the **futures**, whose price gets rewritten every day. No wonder!